# expand the size of QPaintDevice after it is initialzed

Tags: python, pyqt, splash-screen, qpainter

## A little Context

I'm trying to make a `QSplashScreen` with a custom animation. I've tried many different approaches, with each failures. Mostly, my main technique was to create a new Class which inherits from `QSplashScreen` and then plan with the `paintEvent()`. It worked... ish. The animation is not the problem, It is really the QPaintDevice which seems corrupted.

Because I was calling the `super(classname, self).__init__(args)` only way after in my init and passing it arguments that I modified in the init, I always had corrupted pixels; The image was in weird tones and had lines of colorful pixels in the background. Sometimes it is patterns sometimes it is completely random.

[image]

I have tried changing every line of code and the only thing that removed those lines was calling the `super()` at the beginning of the `__init__`. Unfortunately, I was making a frame that I was passing to the init. Now that this isn't possible, I would like to modify the size of the `QPaintDevice` on which my `QSplashScreen` initializes, because my animation is displayed beyond that frame. I won't post all the code since the custom animation is quite heavy.

## Minimal Working Exemple

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSplashScreen, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize, pyqtSignal, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QIcon, QBrush
import time, sys


class FakeAnimatedSplash(QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.newFrame = QPixmap(self.image.size()+QSize(0, 20))
        super(FakeAnimatedSplash, self).__init__(self.newFrame, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), Qt.transparent)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.image.rect(), self.image)
        painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(0, 110), 8, 8)


class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        super(App, self).__init__(sys_argv)
        self.main = QMainWindow()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
        self.newSplash()
        self.main.show()

    def newSplash(self):
        pixmap = QPixmap("yourImage.png")
        smallerPixmap = pixmap.scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        splash = FakeAnimatedSplash(smallerPixmap)
        splash.setEnabled(False)
        splash.show()
        start = time.time()
        while time.time() < start + 10:
            self.processEvents()


def main():
    app = App(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("ABB_icon.png"))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Potential Solution

Changing the `super()` to the beginning makes it work but reduces the QPaintDevice window which hides my animation. I would like to expand it, but there are no methods which can do it after the initialization.

```
    def __init__(self, image):
        super(LoadingDotsSplash, self).__init__(image, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.image = image
        # here a function or method that changes the size of the QPaintDevice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that newFrame is an uninitialized QPixmap and for efficiency reasons the pixels are not modified so they have random values, and that is because the size of the FakeAnimatedSplash is larger than the QPixmap that is painted. The solution is to set the value of the newFrame pixels to transparent:

```py
class FakeAnimatedSplash(QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        pix = QPixmap(self.image.size() + QSize(0, 20))
        pix.fill(Qt.transparent)
        super(FakeAnimatedSplash, self).__init__(pix, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), Qt.transparent)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.image.rect(), self.image)
        painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(0, 110), 8, 8)
```

Comment: Always got the answer for everything! Thanks!

Comment: I had thought that the painter.fillRect in the paintEvent served that purpose.